# Switch view of content depending on click React-Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-ios

I am new in react native.

My question is pretty simple: On click on user, the content of modal will change, if user is  `user.type === type.Renter`, I need to show first View, else If `user.type === type.Consultant`, I need to show second view which is commented.
Thank you all :)

```
interface IModalProps {
    onPressClose: () => void;
    user: IUser | null;
    onPressNavigate: () => void;
}

export const UserInfoModal = (props: IModalProps) => {
    const { onPressClose, user, onPressNavigate } = props;
    const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
    const landscape = width > height;

    return (
        <Modal animationType='slide' visible={!!user} transparent={true}>
            <View style={[styles.mainContainer, globalStyles.Shadow, { width: isTablet() ? '70%' : '80%' }]}>
                <WZCircleButton onPress={onPressClose} style={styles.closeButton} iconUri={require('@assets/icons/close-button.png')} />
                <View>
                    <WZText style={styles.headerTitle}>{user?.displayName}</WZText>
                    <WZText style={styles.title}>{Strings.ChatScreen.SchoolStreet}</WZText>
                    <WZUserAvatar style={styles.userAvatar} size={150} user={user} />
                    <WZText style={styles.subTitle}>{Strings.ChatScreen.ProfileText}</WZText>
                    <WZButton onPress={onPressNavigate} text='Start Chat' style={styles.buttonStartChat} />
                </View>
            </View>
            {/* <View style={[styles.mainContainer, globalStyles.Shadow, { width: isTablet() ? '70%' : '80%' }]}>
                <WZText style={styles.headerTitleConsultant}>{Strings.ChatScreen.SearchByResidentByFirstName}</WZText>
                <View>
                    <WZText>{Strings.ChatScreen.Email}</WZText>
                    <WZText>{Strings.ChatScreen.EmailInfo}</WZText>
                    <WZButton style={styles.buttonStartChat} text={Strings.ChatScreen.EmailButton}></WZButton>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <WZText>{Strings.ChatScreen.WalkInHours}</WZText>
                    <WZText>{Strings.ChatScreen.WalkInHoursInfo}</WZText>
                </View>
            </View> */}
        </Modal>
    );
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a more detailed description of the types you want to compare

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const UserInfoModal = (props: IModalProps) => {
    const { onPressClose, user, onPressNavigate } = props;
    const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
    const landscape = width > height;

    const renderRenterView = () => (
          <View style={[styles.mainContainer, globalStyles.Shadow, { width: isTablet() ? '70%' : '80%' }]}>
                <WZCircleButton onPress={onPressClose} style={styles.closeButton} iconUri={require('@assets/icons/close-button.png')} />
                <View>
                    <WZText style={styles.headerTitle}>{user?.displayName}</WZText>
                    <WZText style={styles.title}>{Strings.ChatScreen.SchoolStreet}</WZText>
                    <WZUserAvatar style={styles.userAvatar} size={150} user={user} />
                    <WZText style={styles.subTitle}>{Strings.ChatScreen.ProfileText}</WZText>
                    <WZButton onPress={onPressNavigate} text='Start Chat' style={styles.buttonStartChat} />
                </View>
            </View>
    )

    const renderConsultantScreen = () => (
        <View style={[styles.mainContainer, globalStyles.Shadow, { width: isTablet() ? '70%' : '80%' }]}>
                <WZText style={styles.headerTitleConsultant}>{Strings.ChatScreen.SearchByResidentByFirstName}</WZText>
                <View>
                    <WZText>{Strings.ChatScreen.Email}</WZText>
                    <WZText>{Strings.ChatScreen.EmailInfo}</WZText>
                    <WZButton style={styles.buttonStartChat} text={Strings.ChatScreen.EmailButton}></WZButton>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <WZText>{Strings.ChatScreen.WalkInHours}</WZText>
                    <WZText>{Strings.ChatScreen.WalkInHoursInfo}</WZText>
                </View>
            </View>
    )

    return (
        <Modal animationType='slide' visible={!!user} transparent={true}>
            {user.type === type.Renter ? renderRenterView() : renderConsultantView()}
        </Modal>
    );
};
```